# How do you set the value of a AngularJS dropdown menu via Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm using Selenium in Python to log into a site and then set up certain values some of which are held in dropdown menus. In Chrome, when I inspect the dropdown menu, I get the following information:

[image]

The dropdown menu looks like this with these options:
[image]

There are multiple dropdown menus on this page. How would I change this specific dropdown menu's value when it seems that there is no unique ID for this element?

Here's the code I have so far for clicking on the `login` button, entering my credentials and logging in:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

PATH = "/Users/mikefenty/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://www.binarycent.com/")

link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Login")))
link.click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[ng-model='email']"))).send_keys(<login ID>)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[ng-model='password']"))).send_keys(<password>)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='ui primal']"))).click()

#EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='ui button green']"))



driver.quit()
```

Comment: Show your code trial and errors and add the html code as code not screenshot. No one will write that for you.

Comment: Can we have page url if it's public ? or relevant HTML ?

Comment: It's binarycent.com, but the account is not public. I posted what I thought was the relevant HTML above. That's the HTML that pertains to the dropdown menu I'm trying to connect to.